# How can I print a table without one of its columns?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I print the whole table but not the ending td that contains the delete button?

[image]

Comment: you post doesn't hold much water, sorry.

Comment: oho i missed a picture

Comment: you used too many tags and no code for anyone to help you with.

Comment: #Fred-ii Actually i am newer to this site and have not much idea about its criteria about posting... but as soon i got problem i post my query here in order to solve my problem

Comment: @AtifBhatti You can start here to learn more about our quality standards for questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also, this page can help you with formatting your post: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1):

```
@media print{
table td:last-child, th:last-child{
  display:none!important;
  }
}
```

```js
$("#print").on("click",function(){
  window.print();
});
```

```css
td{border:solid 1px #000;font-size:25px;}
@media print {
table td:last-child{
  display:none;
}

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>test </td>
    <td>test </td>
    <td><input type="button" value="delete"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test </td>
    <td>test </td>
    <td><input type="button" value="delete"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<input type="button" id="print" value="print"/>
```

Comment: The OP probably wants `td:last-child, th:last-child` instead of `button`.

Comment: I edited the code. I did not see the image. Thank you

Comment: Farhad  ...i have tried it too but not working ...

Comment: i am getting data using ajax from select.php and table is in exam.php as show below                                                                                      <div class="container">   
                <div class="table-responsive">  
                     <h3 STYLE="color:red;" align="center">Current Marks 
                     Sheet (Editable)</h3><br />  
                     <div id="live_data"></div>                 
                </div>  
           </div>

Comment: this is ajax getting table data from select.php                                $.ajax({
    url:"select.php",
    method:"post",
    data:{
     section:section,
     clas:clas,
     test_name:test_name,
     test_type:test_type,
     date:date
    },
    dataType:"text",
    success:function(data){
     $('#live_data').html(data);
    }
    
    
   });

Comment: I modify the code, please put it in a full screen mode and then print it. Works properly

Comment: Thanks dear it is working perfectly .it solved my problem .

Comment: You're welcome. If it was helpful, please confirm for help others.